# before_save callback in batmanjs

Tags: batman.js

What is the correct to call `after_save` and `before_save` callbacks methods in batman.js?
I'm looking for something similar to what rails provides.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Check out this blog post: http://rmosolgo.github.io/blog/2014/03/19/batman-dot-model-lifecycle-callbacks/

Hope it helps!

---

I just looked into this myself. I found that a nice way to get this functionality was to put a listener on the record as soon as it was constructed, taking advantage of the Model's lifecycle:

```
class App.Thing extends Batman.Model
   constructor: ->
     super # instantiates the record

     @get('lifecycle').onEnter 'save', =>
       console.log('about to save!')

     @get('lifecycle').onExit 'save', =>
       console.log('just saved!')

     @ # return the record
```

This isn't documented much yet, but you can see the full record lifecycle (steps, names, order, etc!) described in [the tests](https://github.com/batmanjs/batman/blob/master/tests/batman/model/record_lifecycle_test.coffee)!